# Jsch connection with private key fails with com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail error

Tags: ssh, jsch, private-key

I'm trying to connect to remote server via ssh using Jsch.
I can successfully connect with bash command:

```
ssh -p 999 -i ~/.ssh/private_key.pem server_name
```

But when I try with Jsch with following configuration, connection fails with    `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail`

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession("user_name", "server_name", 999);
jsch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/private_key.pem");
session.connect(30000);
```

Tried with and without specifying hosts file. And also with `"PreferredAuthentications" : "privatekey"` - the same result

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the key, once I changed the key from a private to the proper public key I was able to connect.